# Assign a factor vector with more than 2 levels/labels for a given numeric numeric vector

Tags: r, refactoring, recode

everybody. I hope that you would help me to solve my query.
For a vector representing the price ($) of apples say,

```
apple <- c(23, 26, 54, 34, 34, 34, 98, 23, 4, 34, 098, 45, 93, 20, 39, 83, 78, 34, 09, 8, 56, 98, 99, 62, 29)
```

I can assign a factor vector that represents whether it is "cheap" if apples cost less than $50 and "expensive" if apple cost more than or equal to $50. For instance, the factor variable could easily be assigned as:

```
price <- factor(apple>50, labels = c("cheap", "expensive"))
```

However, I am clueless of assigning a factor variable with three levels of price say cheap, moderate, and expensive, say when apples are said to be of a moderate price if they cost between $30 and $40.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `cut`:

```
 cut(apple, breaks = c(0, 30, 40, Inf), labels = c("Cheap", "Moderate", "Expensive"))
#>  [1] Cheap     Cheap     Expensive Moderate  Moderate  Moderate  Expensive Cheap    
#>  [9] Cheap     Moderate  Expensive Expensive Expensive Cheap     Moderate  Expensive
#> [17] Expensive Moderate  Cheap     Cheap     Expensive Expensive Expensive Expensive
#> [25] Cheap    
#> Levels: Cheap Moderate Expensive
```

Comment: Very nice solution. You could replace `100` with `Inf` in case of very expensive apples. ;-)

Comment: Thanks @MartinGal I just realised that made more sense. I guess you could also make the lower value -Inf if anyone wanted to give money away with their apples!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `findInterval` in `base R`

```
c('Cheap', 'Moderate', 'Expensive')[findInterval(apple, c(0, 30, 40))]
#[1] "Cheap"     "Cheap"     "Expensive" "Moderate"  "Moderate"  "Moderate"  "Expensive" "Cheap"     "Cheap"     "Moderate"  "Expensive"
#[12] "Expensive" "Expensive" "Cheap"     "Moderate"  "Expensive" "Expensive" "Moderate"  "Cheap"     "Cheap"     "Expensive" "Expensive"
#[23] "Expensive" "Expensive" "Cheap"
```